# C# Cursor and PictureBox

Tags: c#-4.0, cursor, picturebox

When ever my PictureBox is created, the cursor position in at x=0,y=0 which is the top left corner of the PictureBox. I want to place my Cursor in the center.

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 75, Cursor.Position.Y - 75);
```

I tried doing this but it didn't helped. As the size of my PictureBox is 150,150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cursor.Position = this.PointToScreen(new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + pictureBox1.Width / 2 ,pictureBox1.Location.Y + pictureBox1.Height / 2 ));
```

Comment: Well to some extent thank you :)... But the problem that is coming now is, Cursor is at the center for the first time when the program starts. As I am changing the PictureBox location on mouse click event, so the cursor again appears on the top left corner

Comment: How are you changing the PictureBox location?

Comment: pie.Location = e.Location;  
    Controls.Add(pie);

Comment: But how are you moving the picturebox? In what event? Please edit your question with more details about your problem.